# How do I display the index of the asset in assets loop?

Tags: templating, assets

Looking to do something like this:

```
{% for image in block.images %}
    <img src="{{ image.url }}" data-index="{{ image.index }}">
{% endfor %}
```

This seems like it should be easy and I feel like I've done it before, however I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
{% for key, image in block.images %}
    {{ key }} - <img src="{{ image.url }}" data-index="{{ key }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Keep in mind that's a 0 based array, so the first image will output 0, the 2nd 1, etc.